# Loop through different ranges in vba

Tags: vba, loops, range, names

I'm a newbie with VBA and am trying to loop through different ranges. My goal is to add an additional name for a number of ranges in order to preform calculations on them.

I have a mapping table set up, with one column being the old name and another the new name. My plan was to do a vlookup on the mapping table to get the new name, and add the name with the result.

Here is my code, the error I am getting is 'Application-defined or object-defined error'

```
Sub RenameColsUsingMap()
Dim rnge As String

For nm = 1 To 52
    rnge = Cells(3, nm).Value
    If rnge <> "" Then

        ActiveWorkbook.names.Add _
            Name:=WorksheetFunction.VLookup(rnge _
                    , Worksheets("mapPlaceholder").Range("B2:C1000") _
                    , 2 _
                    , False) _
            , RefersToR1C1:=Worksheets("701421").Range(rnge)
        'Worksheets("701421").Range(rnge).Select
    End If
Next nm

End Sub
```

Through debugging this, I've concluded the bug is in this line

```
RefersToR1C1:=Worksheets("701421").Range(rnge)
```

meaning that the successful execution of this code should be sufficient to fix the problem with the first batch (it is simplified)

```
Sub RenameColsUsingMap()
Dim rnge As String

For nm = 1 To 52
    rnge = Cells(3, nm).Value
    If rnge <> "" Then
        Worksheets("701421").Range(rnge).Select
    End If
Next nm

End Sub
```

does anyone see anything wrong with this?

Comment: Try removing the `R1C1` from the `RefersToR1C1` unless you reference is in R1C1 format: `R[]C[]:R[]C[]`

Comment: @JohnColeman fair point. is is part of a larger line.I picked the line apart and the Vlookup part works, but the range does not. Furthermore, selecting that range (in the second bit of code) does not work either

Comment: Try selecting the range without the worksheet reference, as it most likely is a workbook named range: `Range(rnge).Select`

Comment: @ScottCraner This gives me the error 'method 'range' of object '_global' failed'